# Best way to get data from a url within a browser program using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to change my command line js app to run in the browser instead in attempt to learn UI design. I was using nodejs to request an html and extract some simple text from it, but require is not compatible in browser. I know i can use browserify but is there a better, "go-to" option for this kind of task aside from forcing myself to use nodejs?

Thanks

Comment: Webpack is like the swiss-army knief to compile js to run on various platforms: https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: I had considered browserify to be the "go-to" option for converting node.js to browser-compatible code.

Comment: ok thanks i guess i will just go with browserify